# Need to know the way to stamp a field within a document collection which is in a repeat control

Tags: controls, xpages, repeat

I have a repeat control which has its source as a notesdocumentcollection. Inside the repeat control I have a panel that has a datasource and the document id property of the datasource is set to the universal id of the a single document which in my case is the repeat control variable apprDoc (apprDoc.getUniversalID). Thus using the panel datasource I am trying to directly bind each field in the repeat control to the respective back end document. I have a submit button on click of which I need to post the values selected by the user into the backend document and  also set some other fields which are not bound to the back end document. I need to get a handle to each document in the document collection in order to set a field value on the backend document. Can someone please suggest a way to do the same, or any other way to achieve the functionality which I am trying to achieve. Please find below the code for the same:

```
    <xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="apprDoc" indexVar="docIndex"
            first="0">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:// Look up the employee details view to get the employee appraisal details from the current database
    var curDB:NotesDatabase = session.getCurrentDatabase();
    var vwlkApprView:NotesView = curDB.getView("vwlkAllApprApper");
    var collDocAppr:NotesDocumentCollection = vwlkApprView.getAllDocumentsByKey(sessionScope.EmployeeID);
    if(collDocAppr.getCount() != 0){
        return collDocAppr;
    }
return null;}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:panel id="pnlFG">
                <xp:this.data>
                    <xp:dominoDocument formName="frmAppraisal" var="appraisalDoc"
                        action="editDocument" documentId="#{javascript:apprDoc.getUniversalID();}">
                        <xp:this.querySaveDocument><![CDATA[#{javascript:var apprDoc:NotesDocument = appraisalDoc.getDocument();
if(requestScope.SubmitFG == true){
    apprDoc.replaceItemValue("CurrFGRRStatus","1");
    apprDoc.save();
}}]]></xp:this.querySaveDocument>
                    </xp:dominoDocument>
                </xp:this.data>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td styleClass="tdCls" style="width:2%">
                        <xp:label id="SrNo">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var index = parseInt(docIndex)
index = index + 1;
index.toString();}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td styleClass="tdCls" style="width:20.0%">
                        <xp:label id="ApeName">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return apprDoc.getItemValueString("AppraiseeName");}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td styleClass="tdCls" style="width:15.0%">
                        <xp:label id="ApeGrade">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return apprDoc.getItemValueString("Appraisee_Grade");}]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td styleClass="tdCls" style="width:15.0%">
                        <xp:div style="text-align:center">
                            <xp:label id="appeTotImpRate"
                                style="font-size:10pt;color:rgb(255,0,0);font-weight:bold">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return apprDoc.getItemValueDouble("AppeTotImpRate").toFixed(2);}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:label>
                        </xp:div>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td styleClass="tdCls" style="width:15.0%">
                        <xp:div style="text-align:center">
                            <xp:label id="apprTotImpRate"
                                style="color:rgb(255,0,0);font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return apprDoc.getItemValueDouble("ApprTotImpRate").toFixed(2);}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:label>
                        </xp:div>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td styleClass="tdCls" style="width:15.0%">
                        <xp:div style="text-align:center">
                            <xp:label id="revTotImpRate"
                                style="font-size:10pt;color:rgb(255,0,0);font-weight:bold">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return apprDoc.getItemValueDouble("RevTotImpRate").toFixed(2);}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:label>
                        </xp:div>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td styleClass="tdCls" style="width:10.0%">
                        <xp:div style="text-align:center">
                            <xp:comboBox id="appeGrades"
                                value="#{appraisalDoc.ApperFinalGrade}" style="width:50.0px"
                                disableClientSideValidation="true">
                                <xp:this.validators>
                                    <xp:validateRequired>
                                        <xp:this.message><![CDATA[#{javascript:var index = parseInt(docIndex)
index = index + 1;
"Please select a final grade in row number " + index.toString();}]]></xp:this.message>
                                    </xp:validateRequired>
                                </xp:this.validators>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="-"
                                    itemValue="">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="1"
                                    itemValue="1">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="2"
                                    itemValue="2">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="3"
                                    itemValue="3">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="4"
                                    itemValue="4">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="5"
                                    itemValue="5">
                                </xp:selectItem>
                            </xp:comboBox>
                        </xp:div>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:panel>
        </xp:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about a button with the simple action "save data sources"? That should save all data sources available on the XPage.

Comment: Yes I am able to save all the documents using the same method as mentioned by you. The challenge is this will only save the fields that have a value binding. Apart from the fields that are have a value binding I also need to set some fields directly into the back end documents in the collection, this is required to maintain the status of these documents in my workflow.

Comment: Just to add, I tried to set the fields on querydocumentsave() event of the data-source defined within the panel and it did set the field with values but in this case it ended up creating save conflicts and also it did not set the fields which had the value binding defined.

Comment: I see... try adding a script action to the "save datasources" button which runs after "save datasources". In the script action, use documentCollection.stampAll(). it's a good chance this will work and not produce save conflicts. One other idea is to use the postSave event and do a document.getDocument().save(), but this would be slower.

Comment: Thanks a ton I tried the second menthod suggested by you (saving it in the postSave()) and it worked without creating conflicts. In case I want to use the first method you suggested how would I get the reference to the documentCollection object on the button click as the collection is within the repeat control. I am sorry if this seems to be a silly question but I am just a beginner in x-Pages.

Comment: Try to get out of the habit of using `replaceItemValue`... `appraisalDoc.setValue("CurrFGRRStatus","1")` will produce the desired result without the side effects of `replaceItemValue`.

Answer (score 0):

The computation of the repeat elements isn't very efficient - the JSF lifecycle will make you lookup the values twice. You could try this instead:

```
// If we looked them up before we don't need to do anything
if (viewScope.approveIDs) {
   return viewScope.approveIDs;
}
// Look up the employee details view to get the employee appraisal details from the current database
var curDB:NotesDatabase = session.getCurrentDatabase();
var vwlkApprView:NotesView = curDB.getView("vwlkAllApprApper");
var collDocAppr:NotesViewEntryCollection = vwlkApprView.getAllEntriesByKey(sessionScope.EmployeeID);
// Don't do a count, slow!
var result = new java.util.Vector();
// Add all unids
var ve:NotesViewEntry = collDocAppr.getFirstEntry();
while (ve != null) {
    var nextVe = ve.getNextEntry(ve);
    result.add(ve.getUniversalId()); // eventually check to avoid categories?
    ve.recyle();
    ve = nextVe;
}
viewScope.approveIDs = result.isEmpty() ? null : result;
collDocAppr.recyle();
vwlkApprView.recycle();
return viewScope.approveIDs;
```

This code (off my memory, so check syntax) has a few notable properties:

- Error handling is missing, so please add `try { } catch(e ) { }` generously
- .recyle() is used to release memory
- ViewEntryCollection instead of DocumentCollection -> better performance
- UNIDs are cached in a Vector, so this needs to run only once
- the variable apprDoc now directly contains the unid, saving a document call in the panel
- the variable docIndex can be used with viewScope.approveIds.get() to get access to the ID too
- you could easily extend the example instead of Stings in the vector use a custom object (bean) and get rid of the data sources (might eventually help performance) if you get all fields into the view, so you can continue to use the viewNavigator